# Detect pipe server with same name in global namespace

Tags: c#, wcf, synchronization, named-pipes

**Question:** Is there a way how to quickly check whether particular pipename is being hosted in session 0 - preferabely during the ServiceHost.Open call?

**Scenario:**

Two processes *PipeHost* and *PipeUser* are trying to communicate on the system via pipe with name *PeacePipe*. They are not required to be started with special privileges.

*PipeHost* is started and hosts the *PeacePipe* without any problem.

*PipeUser* is started and connects to *PeacePipe* without any problem.

*PipeUser* tries to comunicate to *PipeHost* via *PeacePipe*, it sends messages but *PipeHost* doesn't see anything.

In fact *PipeUser* connected to *DifferentPipeHostInSession0* that is hosting pipe with same name (but OS creates different pipe) in an elevated (or service) process.

**Background:**

[ServiceHost.Open](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.servicemodel.servicehost.open) should throw AddressAlreadyInUseException when the selected pipename is already being hosted.

However it's not thrown if the pipe is hosted in session 0 and you are attempting to host the same pipe in different sessions. As windows named pipes are normally not te be used accross sessions. With the exception of pipe hosted in session 0. Any process can connect to such a pipe. This can lead to the above sceanrio.

**Code:**

```
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        void Ping();
    }

    [ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single, ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Multiple, IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults = true)]
    public class Service: IService
    {
        public void Ping()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Client Pinged me");
        }
    }

    private static readonly Uri _pipeUri = new Uri("net.pipe://localhost/aaa");
    private static readonly Binding _pipeBinding = new NetNamedPipeBinding(NetNamedPipeSecurityMode.None);

    static void PipeHostTest()
    {
        ServiceHost serviceHost = new ServiceHost(new Service(), _pipeUri);
        serviceHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IService), _pipeBinding, "");

        try
        {
            //Fail here if same pipe already opened - even in Global space
            serviceHost.Open();
            Console.WriteLine("OPENED");
        }
        catch (AddressAlreadyInUseException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e);
            throw;
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    static void PipeClient()
    {
        ChannelFactory<IService> channelFactory = 
            new ChannelFactory<IService>(_pipeBinding, new EndpointAddress(_pipeUri));
        var proxy = channelFactory.CreateChannel();

        proxy.Ping();
    }


    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        if (args.Any())
        {
            PipeClient();
        }
        else
        {
            PipeHostTest();
        }
    }
```

Run once without parameters elevated, once without parameters non-elevated. Both processes will host pipe with same name - but those are different pipes.
Then run once with any parameter. Client process will conect to the pipe hosted by elevated process.

**Possible Solution:**
Use a named mutex in global session `new Mutex(true, "Global\\MutexForMyPipeName", out createdNew)` to see if there is another process trying to do the same.

This however disqualifies even scenarios where the pipes are in 2 different sessions that do not colide.

Preferabely the ServiceHost.Open would take care about this for me as I'm using multiple bindings types (net.tcp, net.pipe, net.udp) and have single code for creating and hosting the ServiceHost. NamedPipes are the only ones that can allow creation of new host without AddressAlreadyInUseException exception while the address is actuall already in use.

Answer (score 0):

Pipes do not have namespaces like other kernel objects.
Multiple servers for same pipe is a 'feature', see [CreateNamedPipe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-createnamedpipea) `nMaxInstances`.
See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/7572877/5647513